# How to reverse this simple xor encryption function?

Tags: xor

this code decrypts encrypted rom code from an arcade game pcb (it is from source code of Mame emulator)

for each byte in rom...

```
int src, dst;
src = 0xd7;    // example value
dst = 0;
if (( src & 0x01) == 0x01) dst ^= 0x04;
if (( src & 0x02) == 0x02) dst ^= 0x21;
if (( src & 0x04) == 0x04) dst ^= 0x01;
if ((~src & 0x08) == 0x08) dst ^= 0x50;
if (( src & 0x10) == 0x10) dst ^= 0x40;
if (( src & 0x20) == 0x20) dst ^= 0x06;
if (( src & 0x40) == 0x40) dst ^= 0x08;
if ((~src & 0x80) == 0x80) dst ^= 0x88;
```

result (dst) = 0x3c

how do I reverse this scheme, such that I can get back to 0xd7 from 0x3c?

Comment: First of all, this is off-topic here, but you get some help on the comments. Secondly, Write a code to see what value you can get by xoring the right constants. You will create a table with 26 rows and two columns that will tell about the bits of src if reversible! , 00100111

Comment: def is_set(x, n):
    return x & 2 ** n != 0

list = [0x04,0x21,0x01,0x50,0x40,0x06,0x08,0x88]

for i in range(256):

    output = 0

    for j in range(8):
        if is_set(i,j):
            output = output ^ list[j]

    print(" ", hex(i), hex(output))

Comment: The above is python code for the table construction. Bit inversion of the 4th and 8th bit is your homework

Comment: thanks, ran the python code and generated the table (without the bit inversion), how do I turn it into a reverse function? what is the binary number in the first comment?

Comment: create a list or tuple. That is completely programming question that you know about as a hacker.

Comment: don't understand, could you explain this bit "that will tell about the bits of src if reversible! , 00100111"?

Comment: well I guess there's not much point to this question if the answers get deleted....

Comment: These types of questions are off-topic here, as you were told in the beginning and we provide hints and I did more than that, right?

Comment: the solution in the deleted answer was almost there, figured the rest out in the end, thanks